# Installing BioPython and Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, installation-package, installation-path

I am working with Python 2.7.11. I've working problems on Rosalind.com from scratch, but I decided to try using tools that are openly available- in order to start familiarizing myself with finding and using said packages and extensions. Good thing too, because I can't figure out how to get any of the third party extensions to python installed.

Let's start with Numpy. Which this PDF I'm following to install Biopyton suggests I use. http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/install/Installation.pdf

I'm going in circles looking for isntruction. Everybody wants to send me to some other app that uses Numpy or Biopython, I installed Anaconda and then took it back off.

I hear talk of using 'the terminal', which I think is just my windows command prompt.

I've downloaded the files from the sources for both programs. Do I need to put the files somewhere special first? Before opening the cammand prompt and issuing a command roughly of the form "python setup install"?

I placed both sets of files in my python folder, but then before trying to command prompt realized they both have setup files.

I was looking for a executable setup file, but double-clicking on the setup files I downloaded doesn't seem to have served that purpose.

Does anyone see what it missing here?

Comment: I would have suggested Anaconda - if you want, you can ask separately about the problems you apparently had with it. Anaconda gives you access to both numpy and biopython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to install your modules into your python path. There is some (windows) documentation to that [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) but should be easily addressable from your interpreter. Can't really give you specific instructions without knowing what you're using. But once you set the path anything you put there will be accessible from your interpreter. Which note that all python programs can be treated as modules so if you want to create your own later put them in a similar place or add that path to your python path.